# Monitoring and chaning scroll position in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access the scroll position of a div in angular.js but I can't figure out how.

This is what I have so far:

```
.directive('chatbox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element[0].scrollTop = 200;
            console.log(element);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div chatbox style="overflow: scroll; height:200px;  overflow-x: hidden; scrollTop: 100" >
</div>
```

Should this not change the scroll position on start up?

Comment: Is there any content in this div?

Comment: Yes there is a ng-repeat putting in some chat text. The scrolling is working I just can't set/get the position of it

Answer (score 0):

Since scrollTop is actually a function, the correct syntax would be:

```
element[0].scrollTop(200);
```

EDIT: Also, scrollTop is not a CSS property, so you should take it out of your style attribute. You'll have to use the jQuery scrollTop to set it, like what I typed above.

http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/